regular expression with regexp_like is not working in snowflake
  SELECT 
       'HAB' AS NAME,
       CASE 
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(LIST_TXT, '(^|,)201(,|$)') THEN 'YES' 
       END AS MC_NM
  FROM TABLE1
)
SELECT * FROM HAB;

my reg expression works as expected outside of Snowflake, but it gives me null for MC_NM even though there is LIST_TXT with 201 in it.

the doc's explain in the usage notes section : The function implicitly anchors a pattern at both ends (i.e. '' automatically becomes '^$', and 'ABC' automatically becomes '^ABC$'). To match any string starting with ABC, the pattern would be 'ABC.*'. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_like#usage-notes

REGEXP_LIKE behaves like LIKE with respect to tokens before/after the match clause. So that is the source of your problem.
select column1 as list_txt,
    COLUMN2 AS EXPECTED,
    '(^|,)201(,|$)' as r1,
    REGEXP_LIKE(LIST_TXT, r1) as og,
    REGEXP_COUNT(LIST_TXT, r1) as rc,
    REGEXP_LIKE(LIST_TXT, '.*(^|,)201(,|$).*') as fixed
from values
    ('201', 'match by self'),
    ('xx,201,yy', 'match 2 commas'), 
    ('xx,201', 'match last value'), 
    ('201,yy', 'match first value'),
    ('xx201,yy', 'bad no comma before 201'),
    ('xx,201yy', 'bad no comma after 201');




LIST_TXT
EXPECTED
R1
OG
RC
FIXED




201
match by self
(^|,)201(,|$)
TRUE
1
TRUE


xx,201,yy
match 2 commas
(^|,)201(,|$)
FALSE
1
TRUE


xx,201
match last value
(^|,)201(,|$)
FALSE
1
TRUE


201,yy
match first value
(^|,)201(,|$)
FALSE
1
TRUE


xx201,yy
bad no comma before 201
(^|,)201(,|$)
FALSE
0
FALSE


xx,201yy
bad no comma after 201
(^|,)201(,|$)
FALSE
0
FALSE



Then there is the result to text part, you are wanting a 'yes' or null, so it could be done with a CASE, or a IFF, or NVL2
select column1 as list_txt,
    COLUMN2 AS EXPECTED,
    '(^|,)201(,|$)' as r1,
    REGEXP_LIKE(LIST_TXT, '.*'||r1||'.*') as fixed,
    CASE fixed WHEN TRUE THEN 'yes' end res_1,
    IFF(fixed, 'yes', null) as res_2, 
from values
    ('201', 'match by self'),
    ('xx,201,yy', 'match 2 commas'), 
    ('xx,201', 'match last value'), 
    ('201,yy', 'match first value'),
    ('xx201,yy', 'bad no comma before 201'),
    ('xx,201yy', 'bad no comma after 201');




LIST_TXT
EXPECTED
R1
FIXED
RES_1
RES_2




201
match by self
(^
,)201(,|$)
TRUE
yes


xx,201,yy
match 2 commas
(^|,)201(,|$)
TRUE
yes
yes


xx,201
match last value
(^|,)201(,|$)
TRUE
yes
yes


201,yy
match first value
(^|,)201(,|$)
TRUE
yes
yes


xx201,yy
bad no comma before 201
(^|,)201(,|$)
FALSE
null
null


xx,201yy
bad no comma after 201
(^|,)201(,|$)
FALSE
null
null




I prefer this version, which eschews regular expressions in favor of a LIKE trick:
SELECT 
    'HAB' AS NAME,
    CASE WHEN CONCAT(',', LIST_TXT, ',') LIKE '%,201,%' THEN 'YES' END AS MC_NM
FROM TABLE1;

The above approach first surrounds LIST_TXT on both sides by commas.  It then searches for ,201, inside that CSV list.  This trick avoids the problem of having to search in the first or last number in the CSV list.
